# Passing HTML via Post call using Ajax and jQuery within MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, jquery

I am trying to post some HTML information to a url using the ajax post command

```
var html = "<b>bold</b>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DragDrop/GetData/" + id + "?html=" + html,
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    }
});
```

But of course you can't pass html in the URL, I know this is something easy but it is driving me nuts, how do I do this?

Comment: You're posting JSON in the POST request? Really? Is the server-side script expecting that? Are you sure you don't mean to do a normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` submission, with `data: {html: html}` to let jQuery form-encode the content for you?

Comment: yes you are correct, thanks.

This appears to be working for the html just as text, but when I add any tags, it does not get passed through, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a POST. Why are you trying to pass the content in the URL instead of using `data`?

```
var html = "<b>bold</b>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DragDrop/GetData/" + id,
    data: html,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this would work.

Issue I have now is on the c# side my public ActionResult GetData(string id, string html);  

The variables are all null?

Comment: What does your route for GetData look like? You can also try `data : {html : html}` in your ajax call.

Comment: yes that is correct, it does not allow content that has tags in e.g.   Hello <b>world</b>  it gets ignored

Comment: Have you tried `escaping` the string? `var html = escape("<b>world</b>")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to pass it through query string, you would have to encode it. Here's a jQuery package for encoding it:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/URLEncode